# Can I tag my code on Github when building it through a CDK Pipeline on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, tags, aws-cdk, aws-pipeline

I have some GitHub repositories with my project source codes and I build them through CDK Pipelines on AWS. I basically grab the source code, build the docker images and push them to the ECR. I was wondering if I could tag the versions on the code on GitHub through any step or code on the Pipeline, so I can keep track of the builds on the code. I tried looking it up but didn't find anything so I thought maybe I would have more luck here if anyone has done that.

Answer (score 1):

Here a working example of a pipeline initialization with `CDKv2` using a `CodeCommit` repo:

```js
import { Stack, StackProps, Stage, StageProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Repository } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-codecommit';
import { PolicyStatement } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
import { CodeBuildStep, CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ManualApprovalStep } from 'aws-cdk-lib/pipelines';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
// This will be your infrastructure code
import { InfrastructureStack } from './infrastructure-stack';

export interface PipelineStackProps extends StackProps {
    readonly repository: string;
}

export class PipelineStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PipelineStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'pipelineID', {
            pipelineName: "pipeline-name",
            synth: new CodeBuildStep('Synth', {
                input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(Repository.fromRepositoryArn(this, `repository`, props.repository), 'master'),
                commands: [
                    'npm ci',
                    'npm run build',
                    'npx cdk synth',
                ],
                rolePolicyStatements: [
                    new PolicyStatement({
                        actions: ['ssm:GetParameter'],
                        resources: [`*`],
                    })
                ]
            }),
            dockerEnabledForSynth: true
        });

        pipeline.addStage(new InfrastructureStage(this, 'qa'));
        pipeline.addStage(new InfrastructureStage(this, 'prod'), {
            pre: [new ManualApprovalStep('PromoteToProd')]
        });
    }
}

class InfrastructureStage extends Stage {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StageProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        new InfrastructureStack(this, "InfrastructureStack", {
            environment: id
        })
    }
}
```

If you have a look at the following [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipelineSource.html) you can view that `CodePipelineSource` can interact with `Github` using [GitHubSourceOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.GitHubSourceOptions.html) options and [gitHub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipelineSource.html#static-gitwbrhubrepostring-branch-props) method.